# Understanding and modifing a theorem from Fulton's "algebraic curves"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading Theorem 2 in chapter 3.2 in Fulton.

It says that $mult_p(F)=\dim_k (m_p(F)^n/m_p(F)^{n+1})$ for a sufficiently large $n$. Reading the proof I understood that we eventually play a game of exact sequences, I want to understand what happens if $n$ is not sufficiently large and what does sufficiently large mean.

Say we call $mult_p(F)=k$ (the book uses m, but I am using k to differentiate with the ideals $m_p$)
 So we want to find the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F,I^n)$. Then the book proceeds with saying that if $F$ has multiplicity k then the polynomial can be written as $F=F_k+ F_{k+1}+\cdots$ thus if we have $ F * G \in I^n$ then $G \in I ^{n-m}$.

That is great and we can make the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^{n-m} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F,I^n) \rightarrow 0$$
Then from there their proof is very straight. What I observed is that for "n" to be sufficiently large it must be larger than k ie the multiplicity of the point. ( I think I am correct here but feel free to correct me)
My question is if we say that n is smaller than the k. In that case I think the thing that will change is that we do not need a G anymore thus we will get that
$F \in I ^n$ because the smallest term of F is $F_k$ but k is larger than n so we have the inclusion. Thus the exact sequence that we will obtain is
$$0  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F,I^n) \rightarrow 0$$

To compute the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F,I^n) $ we get 
$\dim \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(F,I^n) = \dim \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^n +1$ but this does not seem to add up. If someone is familiar with Fulton and the argument can possibly guide me I would appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Problem 3.13 deals with precisely what happens when $0\le n<k$. You've got the right idea essentially.

It has been dealt with concisely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2926155/1197945).

Comment: Good find! In the future, when you find a question that is answered by another question on the site, please suggest a duplicate via the "flag" link at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I’ll keep it in mind, thanks.